# resizing the width and height of the bootstrap carousel with the screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a bootstrap carousel like so

```
<div class="container-fluid home">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 slideshow">
        <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="500">
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item active"> <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/image1.jpg" alt="First slide"> </div>
                <div class="carousel-item"> <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/image3.jpg" alt="Third slide"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to resize the images of the carousel according to the screen size of the user just like the `Louis Vuitton` site,the image in the home screen [here](http://au.louisvuitton.com/eng-au/homepage) I have tried all the `SO` solution but nothing seems to work. 
I can get this to work if it is set to background image using the `cover` property on the background but How can I achieve this on a `<img>` tag?

PS: using the Bootstrap alpha 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it looks like you should make the following change:

```
.carousel-item-next, .carousel-item-prev, .carousel-item.active {
  display:block;
}
```

(It was "display:flex;" before).

That allows your images to behave like normal, 100%-width images.

Comment: wait a min I am setting up the fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w70r1Lfx/5/ look at this. the width and height is not resizing . the image is losing it's quality.

Comment: Updated my Answer with a more focused change. You can see the fork here:https://jsfiddle.net/Benihana77/45d33j0r/

Comment: That works! But how do you find out that it was `display:flex` before?

Comment: Some noodling around and Chrome Inspector. Your images were behaving irregularly, so I figured there was some bootstrap class that was forcing odd behavior. I just deleted classes one at a time, starting at the IMG level, until the problem went away (even if it broke other things). Then I went in to see what the class was applying, with Chrome Inspector, and noticed Display:Flex. Nothing inherently wrong with that style, but it requires more definition to work properly, and that was lacking.

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, that's always the best approach to debugging when there's nothing obvious: break things on purpose, piece by piece, and document the effects. It helps you zero-in on where the problem lies, which makes it much easier to fix. Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

I dont recommend you to do that with a image because you will get the image distorted, this is exactly what you want:

```
var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth; 
var bodyHeight = $(window).height();

$(".carousel").each(function(){ 

    $(this).find(".carousel-item img").css({'width':bodyWidth, 'height':bodyHeight});

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xs3wLen6/

If you doesnt want to get the image distorted you should use the image as `background-image` + `background-size:cover`, and set the javascript `width` and `height` to the a container, in yout case `container-item`. something like this (will only work at the first time load):

https://jsfiddle.net/xs3wLen6/2/

The final way i recommend you, is to use a responsive version using a function:

```
function ResponsiveCode() {

    var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth; 
    var bodyHeight = $(window).height();

    if (bodyWidth)
    {
    //responsive code start
    $(".carousel").each(function(){ 

    $(this).find(".carousel-item").css({'width':bodyWidth, 'height':bodyHeight});

    });
    //responsive code end
  }else{
    window.setTimeout(ResponsiveCode, 30);
  }
}

//first launch
ResponsiveCode();

$(window).bind("load", ResponsiveCode);
$(window).bind("resize", ResponsiveCode);
$(window).bind("orientationchange", ResponsiveCode);
```

test here: https://jsfiddle.net/xs3wLen6/3/

Comment: this isn't responsive? I am trying to change the window size but the image remains in the same postion.

Comment: ahh i thought you wanted only on the first time load, i updated the code to a responsive version using a function and moving the main width/height variables to read everytime when resize